# Building a recursive dependent filename parser in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to do something that seems conceptually pretty straightforward, to build a `Parser[File]` for an input task that accepts the name of an existing directory.

The parser would constructed from a base directory (it would be the user's home directory by default), it would tab-complete over subdirectories, and then recursively tab-complete over sub-subdirectories etc.

I have an implementation that *almost* works. It correctly parses existing subdirectories at any depth. However, what is confusing me is that tab completion only works at the top level. The parsing engine can distinguish between incomplete and invalid inputs in recursive subdirectories (it only prints `{invalid input}` when there is no possible completion), but it does not print subdirectory example completions, or tab-complete partially entered directories, below the top level. The `examples` sets are correct (according to some `println` debugging) for recursive subdirectory parsers, but the completion engine seems to ignore them.

I've played around with different placements of `token(...)` deliminators, but that hasn't seemed to have mattered very much.

Here is my implementation:

```
private val fsep = File.separator

private val thisDot = "."
private val upDot   = ".."

private [sbtethereum] def genDirectoryParser( file : File, acceptNewFiles : Boolean ) : Parser[File] = {
  token( Space.* ) ~> token( _genDirectoryParser( file, acceptNewFiles ) )
}

private def _genDirectoryParser( file : File, acceptNewFiles : Boolean ) : Parser[File] = {
  def parsersFromMap( m : immutable.TreeMap[String,File] ) : immutable.Seq[Parser[File]] = {
    immutable.Seq.empty[Parser[File]] ++ m.map { case ( input, f ) => literal( input ).flatMap( _ => _genDirectoryParser( f, acceptNewFiles ) ) }
  }

  if (!file.exists() || !file.isDirectory() || !file.canRead() ) {
    failure( s"'${file.getPath} must exist, and be a readable directory." )
  }
  else {
    val baseParser = Space.*.map( _ => file )
    val subdirs = file.list.map( new File( file, _ ) ).filter( _.isDirectory ).map( _.getName )
    val subdirsMap = immutable.TreeMap.empty[String,File] ++ subdirs.map( name => Tuple2( name + fsep, new File( file, name ) ) )
    val subdirParsers = parsersFromMap( subdirsMap )
    val roots = File.listRoots
    val rootsMap = immutable.TreeMap.empty[String,File] ++ roots.map( r => Tuple2( r.getAbsolutePath, r ) )
    val rootParsers = parsersFromMap( rootsMap )
    val dotsMap = immutable.TreeMap( (thisDot + fsep) -> file, (upDot + fsep) -> file.getParentFile )
    val dotsParsers = parsersFromMap( dotsMap )

    val examples = immutable.TreeSet.empty[String] ++ subdirsMap.keySet ++ rootsMap.keySet ++ dotsMap.keySet

    val residualParser = if ( acceptNewFiles ) {
      def okChar( c : Char ) = ( c >= 48 && c < 58 ) || ( c >= 65 && c < 123 ) || (".-_".indexOf(c) >= 0)
      val fileChar = charClass( okChar, "Acceptable filename characters" )
      fileChar.+.map( chars => new File( file, chars.mkString ) )
    }
    else {
      failure( "Not an existing directory" )
    }

    ( (subdirParsers ++ rootParsers ++ dotsParsers :+ residualParser).foldLeft( baseParser ){ ( last, next ) => last | next } ).examples( examples, !acceptNewFiles )
  }
}
```

My implementation is slightly more complicated than I described. It also accepts stuff like filesystem roots  as well as "dot" path elements (`whatever/../whatever`, etc.), and there's an option to accept names of new files. But I don't think these wrinkles are likely to have much to do with the noncompletion of dependent parsers. (Am I wrong?)

Thanks for any help!